# Current / default directory in vaadin project

Tags: java, vaadin

I am working on reports. Now I have a jrxml file which I have to load so that I can parse it. However, the problem is, I want to load the file with its name directly

```
String path = "myreport.jrxml";
```

But I am unable to find that where should I place that file in my project so that the above path is valid. In simple java project, we just place our desired file in our project folder where src folder is placed, but it is not working in vaadin project. So where should I place my file.

Thanks.

Comment: how are you trying to load it?

Comment: I am loading it in this way JRXmlLoader.load(path). It is a web application.

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying your project to a web server? Then you would need to find out what is the default working directory of that web server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
JRXmlLoader.load("/myreport.jrxml");
```

or if you want to test if the resource is found and take another tries you could load it as a resource and pass it load method from `JRXmlLoader` as follows:

```
JRXmlLoader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myreport.jrxml"));
```

Comment: my question basically is, where should I place "myreport.jrxml" file in my project folder? Whether it is to place within src or somewhere else?

Comment: if you put into the /src folder it should work to load it with the `/` in front of the name. What you are using is a relative path, and this normally leads to mistakes...